# Fetch Craft Commerce purchasable element type

Tags: plugin-development, plugin-craftcommerce

How should I retrieve a purchasable element criteria in Craft Commerce ?

To get entries, I just do

```
craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
```

I have tried the following without any success to get purchasables

```
craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Purchasable);
craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Purchasables);
craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Product);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, Commerce only provides 3 custom element types to Craft... products, orders and variants.

My guess is you're looking for products, in which case the syntax you're looking for is:

```
$productsCriteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria('Commerce_Product');
```